# MFMessageComposeViewController not fullscreen with 4 inch screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, fullscreen, message

My application send messages using MFMessageComposeViewController, this is my code:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = content;
    controller.recipients = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil, nil];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

This worked great with 3.5 inch screen, but i have a problems with 4 inch screen, keyboard not in bottom, seem like this view still use for 3.5 inch screen, after modal view, MessageComposeView have a blank zone in bottom.

Comment: ..and you have Default-568h@2x.png in your app?

Comment: yep, i added it before

Comment: And your xcode version is... ?

Comment: i'm using xcode 4.6 :D